# Selecting UISegmentedControl controls result in SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, uisegmentedcontrol

The objective is to have a MKMapView which switches from mapType by making use of a UISegmentedControl.

When pressing one of the segmented controls however, I get this in my output:

> 2011-09-21 18:36:39.127 ShutterBug[2022:ec03] -[__NSCFData
>   indexOfObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c90700
>   2011-09-21 18:36:39.130 ShutterBug[2022:ec03] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFData indexOfObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x5c90700'

Here is the relevant part of my code, getting SIGABRT on first line of changeMapType:

```
static NSArray *mapTypeChoices = nil;
#define MAP_STREET @"Street"
#define MAP_SATELLITE @"Satellite"
#define MAP_HYBRID @"Hybrid"

- (UISegmentedControl *)mapTypeSegmentedControl
{
    if (!mapTypeChoices) mapTypeChoices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:MAP_STREET, MAP_SATELLITE, MAP_HYBRID, nil];

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:mapTypeChoices];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    switch (self.mapView.mapType) {
        case MKMapTypeStandard: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [mapTypeChoices indexOfObject:MAP_STREET]; break;
        case MKMapTypeSatellite: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [mapTypeChoices indexOfObject:MAP_SATELLITE]; break;
        case MKMapTypeHybrid: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [mapTypeChoices indexOfObject:MAP_HYBRID]; break;
    }

    return [segmentedControl autorelease];
}

- (void)changeMapType:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl
{
    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == [mapTypeChoices indexOfObject:MAP_STREET]) {
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    } else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == [mapTypeChoices indexOfObject:MAP_SATELLITE]) {
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    } else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == [mapTypeChoices indexOfObject:MAP_HYBRID]) {
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    }
}
```

EDIT: debugger is showing me that changeMapType: is called twice when pressed UISegmentedController only once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your static array, `mapTypeChoices`, is being autoreleased. This isn't a class property, so it will not be retained automatically (assuming you would have defined the `retain` property attribute). Don't use the autoreleased initializer for `NSArray`. Use `-initWithObject:` instead.

Comment: Indeed, anything starting with alloc/init/copy retains the returned instance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`mapTypeChoices` is autoreleased when you create it in `mapTypeSegmentedControl`. The memory has been reallocated to something else (`NSData` by the look of it) in the meantime, so it crashes when you try to ask for `indexOfObject`.

Assuming `mapTypeChoices` is a class instance variable, just `retain` it after you create it and you're all set. (Remember to `release` on dealloc, though!

Comment: `mapTypeChoices` is a file-level static variable, so releasing it in `-dealloc` isn't a good idea.